# SASS is compiling uppercase-lowercase filename to lowercase

Tags: css, sass

I'm having a bit of a strange problem. I'm using SASS for the first time, and I'm using it to watch a directory of SCSS files and compiling them to a different directory as CSS. The command I am using is

```
sass --watch client/sass:client/src/components/css
```

However, here's my problem. The file I'm trying to work with currently is "Navbar.module.scss". However, when compiling, it sometimes compiles as Navbar.module.css (Correct), but sometimes compiles as navbar.module.css (Incorrect).

Here is the SASS console output.

```
Compiled client\sass\Navbar.module.scss to client\src\components\css\Navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\navbar.module.scss to client\src\components\css\navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\Navbar.module.css to client\src\components\css\Navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\navbar.module.scss to client\src\components\css\navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\navbar.module.css to client\src\components\css\navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\navbar.module.scss to client\src\components\css\navbar.module.css.
Compiled client\sass\navbar.module.css to client\src\components\css\navbar.module.css.
```

I haven't renamed any files. I've made changes, and saved them - The command is doing the rest.
Each line corresponds to one save.

Edit: Might have found the problem. It was strange, but I was also getting a Navbar.module.css file in the /sass/ folder. I checked my VS Code extensions, and it appears the issue was being caused by the Eno Snippets extension. I thought it was purely for syntax highlighting, but the problem goes away if the extension is disabled and reoccurs if it's enabled. Haven't had an issue since, but since it's intermittent, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Interesting. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes @JeremyHarris. Windows 10 to be specific.

Comment: Does it work consistently if you change your filename to be lowercase? I suspect this is an issue with Windows.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I've added an update to the original post. May have been an issue with a VS Code extension.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense it was a plugin issue. Glad you figured it out.